# Microsoft.ServiceBus in DNX Core 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azureservicebus, servicebus, dnx

I am trying to use `Microsoft.ServiceBus` in **ASP 5** project which targets **dnx451** and **dnxcore50** frameworks and on build it says that it cannot find `Microsoft.ServiceBus` namespace for **dnxcore50** framework.

Should I do something differently or is there no support for **dnxcore50** for `Microsoft.ServiceBus` yet? If so, will there be in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft.ServiceBus binary requires the full .NET 4 framework according to the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/), however the MSDN documentation makes reference to Windows Store and Windows Phone platforms. So while it appears to actually be a PCL, it's not usable by the dnxcore* target. The dnx* target does support full .NET framework libraries however.

Comment: You could alternatively use the REST endpoint to handle this.